# FAS3240 Storage Reports

Tags: netapp

We have two netapp FAS3240 - I am trying to run a storage report. At my last company we were using EMC storage products. You could run reports to show luns, size of luns, what is being used what is available,etc.

For the life of me I cant find how to run reports against the FAS3240. I would be very surprised if the netapp did not have the option available. Perhaps it does not. Does anyone out there have experience with the FAS3240, if so, can you assist me with running reports.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the OnCommand Report software suite to generate the kinds of reports you are talking about.

http://www.netapp.com/us/products/management-software/oncommand-report.aspx